# Access an item of a FirebaseListObservable without *ngFor (in view)

Tags: angular, ionic2, angularfire2

I am using Ionic 2 with AngularFire 2. I am trying to add a messaging functionality in my app.
All chats attached to a user are listed in the /user/user$id/chats/ node in Firebase. And then details of a chat (like messages, ...) are in the /chats/chat$id/ node.

1. I retrieve the list of chats using FirebaseListObservable and pass the id of the chat to a custom component called chat-preview
2. The aim of chat-preview is it display a preview of the last message, its time and the sender ; so chat-preview makes a FirebaseListObservable call to the /chats/chat$id/messages/ node and query it ordered by timestamp and limit to one result (first or last)
3. I get an array of only one item but I don't want to use a *ngFor directive to display it has I know that there will only be one single record...

How can I access it directly from my view ?

*** code ***

chat-preview.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'chat-preview',
  templateUrl: './chat-preview.component.html'
})

export class ChatPreviewComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input()
  chatId: string;

  lastMessage$: FirebaseListObservable<any>;
  recipient$: FirebaseListObservable<any>;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public messageService: MessageService, public userService: UserService) {
    console.log('ChatPreviewComponent constructor');
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('Building chat preview for chat ', this.chatId);
    this.lastMessage$ = this.messageService.getLastMessage(this.chatId);
    console.log('last mess: ', this.lastMessage$);
  }

}
```

chat-preview.comoponent.html

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-avatar item-left>
    <img src="img/avatar-cher.png">
  </ion-avatar>
  <h2>{{chatId}}</h2>
  <p>{{ (lastMessage$ | async)?.content }}</p>
  <!-- prop content of a message is the body of the message -->
  <!-- it looks like it doesn't work because lastMessage$ is actually a list of type FirebaseListObservable -->
</ion-item>
```

Answer (score 1):

As you said, `this.messageService.getLastMessage(this.chatId)` returns FirebaseListObservable, you cannot access it directly.

You need to subscribe to this observable, like this:

```
this.messageService.getLastMessage(this.chatId).
  .subscribe((data) => {
    console.log("Data :",data)
    this._localVar = data;
  },(err) => {
    console.log("Error :",err);
});
```

**NOTE:** You need to get this value in `data` in `.subscribe` section in some local var like `_localVar`. And in html you can use it from `_localVar`.

Also, if you are sure you are going to get only 1 value in an array, access it directly like : `{{_localVar[0].param}}`.

Look at these examples [1](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/558) and [2](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/682) on Github for more understanding.

Comment: I can directly access it from my view with the async pipe which as the same result as subscribing and pass it to a variable. I can reformulate my issue like this : how do I access a certain index of a FirebaseListObservable from view? Combining the async pipe with the array accessor []

Comment: Actually, I do not know the answer to that. Might take some time to find it out as I have not tried it. But, the written answer can give you the exact behaviour that you are looking for. Let me know if you still want the answer to your question using async pipe.

Comment: Indeed your answer works, thanks for answering by the way. I decided to use `.map(array => array[0])`and use it as a classic Observable, rendering it with the async pipe

Comment: Nice. Good learning. Using `.map(array => array[0])`. Actually I knew this. Did not think at the times.

Comment: @ManuelRODRIGUEZ : Could you please close this question if it is working?

Answer (score 0):

.map(array => array[0]) and use it as a classic Observable, rendering it with the async pipe